# Count how many items in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

`books(id, name, category)`
`book_pages(id, book_id)`

**I want to get the number of books that have a `book_page` associated to it.** (There could be books without book pages).

My first instinct was this but it returns many rows.

```
SELECT count(*) as count_table 
FROM books b
GROUP BY b.id 
HAVING ( (SELECT count(*) FROM book_pages bp WHERE bp.book_id = b.id) > 0 )
```

Sorry, I'm sure it's out there on Google somewhere but didn't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `exists`:

```
select count(*)
from books b
where exists (select 1 from book_pages bp where bp.book_id = b.id);
```